# Safari - https 403 Forbidden Access Denied

Tags: ssl, https, safari, fiddler, http-status-code-403

When I try to navigate to a certain https webpage with safari browser, I get a 403 forbidden access denied Server Error. With all the other browsers I get the page displayed without problems. I have searched the web for a solution but I could not find any solution.

Can anyone write me how I can troubleshoot this issue?

Things I have already checked :

- I have checked the certificate that is used. It is the same certificate with Chrome (working) and with safari (not working)
- A very curious behaviour : When I have Fiddler Tool running and capturing while I am trying to connect to the page, the page is displayed without problems. As soon as I deactivate the capturing and try navigating to the page again, I get again 403 Forbidden Access.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanx

Comment: Have you tried spoofing ? (Enable the "Develop menu" in your advanced preferences, then choose "Develop : User Agent : ... ")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was setting in IIS - SSL Settings - Client Certificate - ignore.

Comment: I also removed Require SSL checkbox then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with a **Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter IIS**. The solution to my problem was to:

1. Open up your server remotely
2. Start your IIS manager
3. Under the left **Connections** panel look for the domain that is giving you the problem with the SSL
4. After locating and selecting it click on **SSL Settings**
5. Under **Client certificates** choose **Ignore**
6. Click **Apply** Under the **Actions** section on the right

Done.

Answer (score 0):

See http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-02-28/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app- for a list of common culprits.

What is the URL? Is it on your Intranet? When it is working, do you see HTTP/401 responses in Fiddler before a final HTTP/200?

Comment: I have already seen that link you have sent. Unfortunately, I didnt see anything that could help my situation. The URL is an internal URL. It wont bring anything if I write it here. And about the 401 Responses : Fiddler doesnt show any 401 Responses (with google chrome). It directly shows http/200

Comment: What exactly does *I have checked the certificate that is used.* mean? Is this a *server* certificate or a *client* certificate?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the target website is IP-restricted and the culprit was the new settings of Safari to Hide IP.

[image]